# Accessing instance variables from methods

Tags: ios, xcode

Goal of program: Enter numbers on a viewController. When the user hits Submit button, the data entered by user is passed on to a different class for displaying on a different viewController.

Problem: I am trying to access an instance variable (`numberList`) in an instance method (`-(void)insertNewNumber:(Numbers *)tempNumber`), but it never gives me the correct output. But when I access the same variable through a protocol method of `UITableViewDataSource`, I get the correct answer. I figured this by using NSLog in instance method and protocol method.

Since I have declared `numberList` as a `property` variable, I was thought that I can access it from anywhere in the program and get the correct value stored in it. But compiler returned `0` for the NSLog statements when they were called from instance method.  When the NSLog statements from protocol method, showed the correct result.

Please help me understand why is this occurring and how can I add elements into an array from any method in a program.

Thank you!

Here's the relevant code I am working on:

Numbers.h:

```
@interface Numbers:NSObject

@property (strong, retain) NSString *ID;
@property (strong, retain) NSInteger *number;

@end
```

Numbers.m

```
@implementation Numbers

@synthesize ID, number;

@end
```

DisplayNumbers.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Numbers.h"

@interface DisplayNumbers : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *numberList;

- (void)insertNewNumber:(Numbers *)tempNumber;

@end
```

DisplayNumbers.m:

```
@implementation DisplayNumbers

@synthesize numberList;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    numberList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

    Numbers *num0 = [[Numbers alloc] init];
    Numbers *num1 = [[Numbers alloc] init];

    num0.ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID 0"];
    num0.number = 1111111111;

    num1.ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID 1"];
    num0.number = 2222222222;


    [numberList addObject:num0];    
    [numberList addObject:num1];
```

}

```
- (void)insertNewNumber:(Numbers *)tempNumber
{
    NSLog(@"numberList.count (in -(void)insetNewNumber) = %d", numberList.count);
    [numberList addObject:tempNumber];
    NSLog(@"numberList.count (in -(void)insetNewNumber) = %d", numberList.count);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberList.count (in -(NSInteger)tableView:...) = %d", numberList.count);            
    Numbers *temp = [[Numbers alloc] init];
    temp.ID = @"hi";
    temp.Number = 1234;

    [numberList addObject:temp];

    NSLog(@"numberList.count (in -(NSInteger)tableView:...) = %d", numberList.count);                
   return numberList.count;
}

@end
```

Edit 1: Calling of `insertNewNumber:`.
This method is being called from a different class.

InputNumber.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DisplayNumbers.h"

@interface InputNumber:UIViewController

@property (retain, strong) NSInteger *enteredNumber;
-(void)enteredNumber;

@end
```

InputNumber.m

```
@implementation InputNumber

@synthesize enteredNumber;
-(void)enterNumber
{
    DisplayNumber *temp = [[DisplayNumber alloc] init];
    [temp insertNewNumber:enteredNumber];
}
@end
```

Comment: at which place are you calling `insertNewNumber`?

Comment: Does [insertNewNumber] get called before [viewDidLoad]?

Comment: @onnoweb; @sergio : thank you for your response. Please take a look at Edit 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you allocate your numberList in the `ViewDidLoad` method, be sure to call your `insertNewNumber` method **after** the call to `ViewDidLoad`.

I believe that

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    Numbers *temp = [[Numbers alloc] init];
    temp.ID = @"hi";
    temp.Number = 1234;
    [self insertNewNumber:temp];
   return contactList.count;
}
```

works, right?

If you need to call your `insertNewNumber` method before the call to `ViewDidLoad`, allocate your numberList

```
numberList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in an overloaded `initWithNibName:bundle:` method.

Comment: i like your approach. Can you please explain how adding the method to `initWithNibName` lets me add an element to the array `numberList`?

Comment: Sure. I believe that what you do is allocate your viewController, let's say MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
Then you call [vc insertNewNumber:myNumber] and finally display your viewController (without any number inserted). The problem is that the viewDidLoad method of your viewController has not been called when you allocate it. Hence your numberList has not been allocated (since you alloc. it only in the viewDidLoad method) then any change on it is futile! Hence putting the alloc. in initWith.. will solve it

Comment: (the viewDidLoad method is called when you add the view of your viewController to another view, for example)

Comment: Sorry I did not see your Edit 1. When you perform `DisplayNumber *temp = [[DisplayNumber alloc] init];`, no call to the `viewDidLoad` method is ever made! Try and overload your `init` method of `DisplayNumber` to contain the `numberList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` or try  `DisplayNumber *temp = [[DisplayNumber alloc] init]; temp.numberList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [temp insertNewNumber:enteredNumber];`

Comment: great! i have alloc and init numberList in `initWithNibName`. So after the user enters the number on a viewController (belonging to `InputNumber`), it gets passed on to the view belonging to `DisplayNumber` class. But how do I update the table to include the number entered by the user? I tried calling `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` and `- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, but since I don't know what parameters to use in method call, it fails.Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe you use interface builder. On the left panel of interface builder, right click on your tableView and drag the "delegate" outlet to the "File's owner" placeholder above. By doing so, you mention that the viewController implementation file is the delegate of the tableView. Then the tableView behaves accordingly to what the viewController says, which is what you implemented in the `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: i have already connected `delegate` to `File's Owner`, but it still does not behave as you mentioned. ANy other suggestions?

Comment: `delegate` and `dataSource`? Write a NSLog(@"I'm in') in the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` to check if this method is called indeed, or not...

Comment: Yes. It flashes "I'm in" as soon as I load the view that belongs to `DisplayNumber`. I wish there was a way by which I could send you the code. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17419/discussion-between-ibanez-and-rut)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have an ivar called `numberList`. You need to call the property like this:

```
self.numberList = [NSMutableArray array];
```

No need to alloc/init since you're already using a strong reference.

Every time you refer to that `numberList` object, you need to use `self.numberList`.

```
[self.numberList addObject:num0];
[self.numberList addObject:num1];
```

Comment: @Simon.. thanks for your response. I learnt something new from it. Just for clarification, isn't numberList an ivar? I went through the Apple documentation to understand the properties of `strong` reference, but I did not come across any statement that read I do not have to alloc/init if the reference is strong. Can you please tell me where I can find more info about it? Also, I am confused between using `self` and `_variableName`. Can you please explain me the same or point me to some link? Thanks!

Comment: It's not that you don't have to alloc/init if the reference is strong. It's a better practice to do so since you let the property handle the reference. Since your property is already declared as strong, it means that any assignment of the property will be retained. Same way as when you want to delete the reference, you simply nil out the property. The compiler will take care of releasing the object for you. Of course, all that is kinda obsolete with ARC, but a good practice nonetheless :)